# Safe incremental change of field in MS SQL database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I store parameters in SQL table. One of them needs to be incremented each time an API request comes in.

Is this code safe in terms of not getting two same ParamValues for two concurrent calls?

```
DECLARE @value INT

UPDATE MyTable
SET @value = ParamValue = ParamValue + 1
WHERE ParamName = 'ParameterName'

SELECT @value
```

Using SQL Server 2019 and Azure SQL Database.

Comment: You can do this all in a single statement: `UPDATE MyTable SET ParamValue = ParamValue + 1 OUTPUT INSERTED.ParamValue`

Comment: Yes.  Relational databases will lock the table before the update.

Comment: To be crisp, *if* this is done as a single statement, it will lock the row to block other reads until it finishes writing or it will deadlock and abort the transaction, depending on the query plan.  For something this simple, it will take a U lock on the source table row and the promote it to an X lock when doing the update.  You can use explicit transactions for more complex scenarios and either use serializable txn isolation level or use UPDLOCK hints to achieve the same over multi-statement scenarios.